# Azure Web App PATH Variable Modification

Tags: variables, azure, web-applications, path

I have a Azure Web App web service that utilizes a few third party dlls. One of these dlls requires that the path of its location to be included in the PATH environment variable.  On a typical IIS hosting  its not a problem since the PATH variable can be easy modified in the system properties dialog. Is there a way to modify the PATH enviromennt variable from a Web App project?

Answer (score 0):

Try Azure StartUp tasks to run any cmd on start up and define the commands to set PATH in the start up task cmd. For ref - http://nicoploner.blogspot.com.au/2011/11/setting-environment-variables-in.html